# Disable latest post highlighting on WordPress front page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, menu

Currently the navigation menu (consisting of a list of posts) that appears on the front page of my WordPress site has the most recent post highlighted in it. However I don't want this. Is there a way I can change it so that on the front page the navigation doesn't have an on-state, but on all other post pages it does?

Below is the code that I think it generating it:

```
<li<?php echo((!is_front_page() AND $post->ID == $wp_query->post->ID) ? ' class="selected"' : ''); ?>>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the php inside the `<li>` element tag. Without a link to the website, I can't say for sure, but I think that's what's doing it. Anyway, `$post->ID == $wp_query->post->ID` will almost always return true, since `$post` is `$wp_query->post`. Custom loops can change this, but I'm pretty sure nav menus don't override the global $post variable.

Comment: So do you mean remove the whole string: "<?php echo((!is_front_page() AND "?

Comment: I just tried removing the whole php tag inside the <li> and that did not work. it disabled the menu highlighting across all pages, not just the front page.